# Trigger para Actualizar campo de otra tabla al actualizar registro

Tags: mysql, trigger, revisión-de-código, update, tablas

Hola tengo una BD en mySql, y quiero actualizar un campo de una tabla (protocolo.IDESTADO) cuando se actualiza un campo de otra tabla (las tres firmas de la tabla protocolodiagtec ). He probado de estas tres formas y mi trigger no funciona, no me actualiza el idestado de la tabla protocolo.

1° Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER protocolo_diag AFTER UPDATE ON protocolodiagtec
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
        UPDATE  protocolo
        SET  protocolo.IDESTADO = 3     
        WHERE  protocolo.IDPROTOCOLO = NEW.IDPROTOCOLO AND NEW.IDPROFLABFIRMA1 = 0 AND NEW.IDPROFLABFIRMA2 = 0 AND NEW.IDPROFLABFIRMA3 = 0;
END;
```

2° Trigger:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER protocolo_diag AFTER UPDATE ON protocolodiagtec
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.IDPROFLABFIRMA1 = 0 AND NEW.IDPROFLABFIRMA2 = 0 AND NEW.IDPROFLABFIRMA3 = 0 THEN
        UPDATE  protocolo
        SET  protocolo.IDESTADO = 3     
        WHERE  protocolo.IDPROTOCOLO = NEW.IDPROTOCOLO;
END IF;
END;
```

3° Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER protocolo_diag AFTER UPDATE ON protocolodiagtec
FOR EACH ROW 
IF NEW.IDPROFLABFIRMA1 = 0 AND NEW.IDPROFLABFIRMA2 = 0 AND NEW.IDPROFLABFIRMA3 = 0 THEN
        UPDATE  protocolo INNER JOIN protocolodiagtec
        SET  protocolo.IDESTADO = 3     
        WHERE  protocolo.IDPROTOCOLO = protocolodiagtec.IDPROTOCOLO;
END IF;
```

Comment: ¿Y tus tablas como son?

Comment: protocolo:
IDPROTOCOLO | NOMBRE | FECHA | IDESTADO

protocolodiagtec:

IDPROTOCOLODIAGTEC | IDPROTOCOLO | FECHAINFORME | IDPROFLABFIRMA1 | IDPROFLABFIRMA2 | IDPROFLABFIRMA3

Answer (score 0):

Empecemos por parte, el **1° trigger** que muestras tiene errores semánticos, no puedes hacer un `UPDATE` de la tabla *protocolo* buscando con el `WHERE` con los  campos *IDPROFLABFIRMA1, IDPROFLABFIRMA2, IDPROFLABFIRMA3*, que pertenecen a la tabla *protocolodiagtec*, a pesar de que `MySQL` los va a compilar y va a obedecer a las reglas ya que usas esas dos tablas, te recomiendo que para hacer un `UPDATE` con otra tabla agregues sentencias `JOIN`

El **2° trigger** ya es un error de sintaxis para `MySQL` porque al usar los trigger y hacer consultas con `IF`, debes ocupar `&&`.

Y el **3° trigger** ya es una combinación de errores, ya que vuelves a declarar `AND` para los `IF` y tu `INNER JOIN` esta antes del `SET`.

Por lo tanto, tu consulta debe quedar así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER protocolo_diag AFTER UPDATE ON protocolodiagtec
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.IDPROFLABFIRMA1 = 0 && NEW.IDPROFLABFIRMA2 = 0 && NEW.IDPROFLABFIRMA3 = 0
THEN
        UPDATE  protocolo
        SET  protocolo.IDESTADO = 3 WHERE IDPROTOCOLO = NEW.IDPROTOCOLO;
END IF;
END;
```

Te dejo un [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tTNfmuSamSsDKEQ9yNohJ8/2) para que lo pruebes tu mismo, y si ese no es lo que esperas en tu salida, con gusto te ayudo y edito esta respuesta. Saludos